# How to make google search show my website like this

Tags: php, xml, database, search

When searching for some websites on google, it shows the first result like this:

**eBay - New & used electronics, cars, apparel, collectibles**

```
  Motors                            Computers & Networking
  Electronics                       Home & Garden
  Clothing, Shoes & Accessories     Cell Phones & PDAs
  Sporting Goods
```

I guess it has to do with the sitemap...

How can I achieve this layup also whenever users search for my site?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That does not directly has something to do with sitemaps. Google generates those links based on popularity. See http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334 for reference.